# how to make a nodeJS http server acessible externally?

Tags: node.js, http, ip, public

So, I have a nodeJS http server which i tested locally, and it works. But when I try externally, it says, "connection timed out"

Here is my server code:

```
const http = require('http');
const requestListener = function (req, res) {
    console.log(req);
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('NodeJS server testing.');
}

const server = http.createServer(requestListener);
server.listen(8080, "0.0.0.0", () => {
    console.log("http server listening");
});
```

I tried the IP address that shows after typing:

```
hostname -I
```

And it works.

```
$ curl [my-local-hostname]:8080
NodeJS server testing.#
```

But the IP address from

```
$ curl ifconfig.co
```

Or,

```
$ curl ifconfig.me
```

doesn't work.

```
$ curl [my-external-hostname]:8080
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 37.111.219.65 port 8080: Connection timed out
```

I tried from other devices too. But it doesn't work.
Any solutions?

Comment: is port 8080 of your server open for inbound traffic?

Comment: How to do that (without using many libraries?)

Comment: It totally depends on your server. If you are using AWS ec2 instance than go to security group of that instance and allow traffic on port 8080 in inbound rules.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that firewall blocks 8080 port. Try to open port 8080 on server

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to have multiple node apps connect to each other locally?

did you try to access it without the port added on or try changing the port from 8080 to something else, also you might want to try a localhost ip address like http://127.0.0.1:8080

if it is deployed on a server device with a static ip, are you
a) firewalling all incoming connections on port 8080
b) using some sort of http server that deals with incoming connections like nginx, with a proxy pass ?

Comment: No. I am trying to make it available from the internet. And yes, I did try changing port. It did not work